# Multiple Windows on Startup

Tags: swift, xcode6, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I currently have 2 windows in my storyboard. I am able to get one of the windows to show up by selecting it as the inital window. however i am not able to get both windows to pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to have both up at the start, you could always create a named show segue from the first window to the second in storyboard, then in the viewDidLoad of the first window you can make the second window popup with:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueName", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

An application can have *only one window* unless you have an application which also has an external display. Once launched, the window is not removed until the application is destroyed either by you or the OS. What you probably need are views within the window. You can have more than one view in the window or have multiple views each under the control of a view controller and then as suggested by Jeremy Pope you can segue from a main view (declared as a "Initial View Controller") to the second view. Alternately, you can control both views from the same controller and use the "hidden" property of the views to display one or the other or overlap one on the other.

Comment: Considering it was tagged with NSWindow, I assumed he was working on a Mac application, in which case you can have multiple windows.